# Can we apply two coupons on a subscription plan in stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

```
  \Stripe\Subscription::create([
            "customer" => $customer->id,
            "items" => [
                          [
                             "plan" => $aplan_id,
                             "quantity" => $totalQuantity
                          ],
                          [
                             "plan" => $kplan_id,
                             "quantity" => $kidsQuantity
                          ],
                        ],
            "coupon" => $selectedDiscountId, // recursive discount is set in percentage
            "coupon" => 'one-time-free',// one time discount on a plan
  ]);
```

If customer purchased 3 items one should be free as 'coupon' => 'one-time-free' is already set to flat amount 
and above coupon 'coupon' => $selectedDiscountId, is set to recurring discount in percentage.

Next time only first coupon is applied as it is recurring coupon it should be,
and second one should not.

1. first coupon is for one time discount 'flat amount'
2. second coupon is for recursive discount in percentage

Comment: 'coupon' => 'one-time-free' is a discount coupon of flat amount

Comment: I have found a solution, since we cannot add two different coupons on a single subscription, we can add trial period on a plan item and remove that item from subscription and make another one separately. Or we can add "coupon" => 'one-time-free', on other subscription for one time free. Although that subscription only contains free items

Answer (score 1):

Stripe doesn't allow to do this. But, what you can do is, when the invoice is created (Stripe publishes invoice.created event); add a coupon to the invoice item. You need to have logic to determine to which invoice item what coupon should be applied.

```
stripe.InvoiceItem.modify(
    <invoice_item_id>,
    discounts=[{"coupon": <coupon_id>}]
)
```

You can refer to the [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/update?lang=python) documentation